# Vector Space Verification

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I just took an exam asking me if the following are a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ assuming that the set of all real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is a vector space with theoperations $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda f(x)$

$A$= The set of all polynomials in one variable with real coefficients having degree exactly equal to $3$.

$B$=The set of continuous real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$.

$C$= The set of continuous real valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$

**My brief answers:**

$A$ is NOT a vector space for the zero polynomial is not included. $B$ is a vector (showed that zero is in the space, and that closure under addition and multiplication hold. $C$ is NOT a vector space as it is not closed under addition $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=2 \notin C$. Can anyone concur? Thank you.

Comment: Correct, though in the third one isn't it easier to remark  that zero, again, isn't in the set?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to check zero first.

Comment: :-) @DonAntonio As long as I get them right lol. But you're definitely correct I was super nervous.

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct, since the “identity” polynomial $\mathrm{O}(x)=0$ doesn't have degree $3$, hence not in that set.
2. True, as if $f$ and $g$ are in $B$ then, $$(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=0=f(1)+g(1)=(f+g)(1).$$ The same comment can be made for scalar multiplication.
3. Correct, remarking that the “identity” function $0:x\mapsto 0$ isn't in that set would have been faster.